# When using Ruby how do I add a character count to a text area?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to add a character count displayed beneath comment. I don't really know where to start, but this is what I have done so far. I know there needs to be something after the <%= comment.comment %> line.....

```
 <strong>Comment:</strong>
   <%= comment.comment %>
 </p>
 <p>
```

Comment: Do you need anything more complicated than `<%= comment.comment.size %>`?

Comment: not really, i can play around with it now to display it how i want. if i was to go one further and have a character count for all comments on a page, how would that look? 
thanks!!

Comment: You could accumulate the total with lines like `<% total = 0 %>` and `<% total += comment.comment.size %>`, but they would be ugly. Post your controller code, and we can probably add the accumulator there much more cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the number of characters in the `comment` string, all you need is:

```
<%= comment.comment.size %>
```